# Grabar en SQL Server pasando el contenido en imágenes de un DataTransfer de jscript al lado servidor en un aspx

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, json, aspx

Después de un tiempo dedicado a otros temas, debo retomar mi proyecto de nuevo y vuelvo a estar en el mismo agujero atascado.

Agradecería comentarios, ayudas y ejemplos. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Tengo un proyecto web donde ya almaceno de manera correcta datos del form en la bbdd mediante el uso de Store procedures.

He querido añadir una nueva funcionabilidad donde arrastrando imágenes, las visualice durante la carga visual a la página y al guardar los datos, volcar dichas imágenes en la bbdd en SQL Server. En concreto será un artículo relacionado con varias imágenes en una relación 1:M.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante el código js que anexo, consigo visualizar en la web las imágenes que arrastro y dichas imágenes las almaceno en un DataTransfer, al cual denomino dataTransfer.

```js
/*! Image Uploader - v1.2.3 - 26/11/2019
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Christian Bayer; Licensed MIT */

(function ($) {

    $.fn.imageUploader = function (options) {

        
        // Default settings
        let defaults = {
            preloaded: [],
            imagesInputName: 'images',
            preloadedInputName: 'preloaded',
            label: 'Arrastra y suelta aqui las imagenes o click para abrir el buscador. Maximo 3 imagenes',
            extensions: ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.svg'],
            mimes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg+xml'],
            maxSize: undefined,
            maxFiles: undefined,
        };

        // Get instance
        let plugin = this;

        // Will keep the files
        let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

        // The file input
        let $input;

        // Set empty settings
        plugin.settings = {};

        // Plugin constructor
        plugin.init = function () {

            // Define settings
            plugin.settings = $.extend(plugin.settings, defaults, options);

            // Run through the elements
            plugin.each(function (i, wrapper) {

                // Create the container
                let $container = createContainer();

                // Append the container to the wrapper
                $(wrapper).append($container);

                // Set some bindings
                $container.on("dragover", fileDragHover.bind($container));
                $container.on("dragleave", fileDragHover.bind($container));
                $container.on("drop", fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

                // If there are preloaded images
                if (plugin.settings.preloaded.length) {

                    // Change style
                    $container.addClass('has-files');

                    // Get the upload images container
                    let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded');

                    // Set preloaded images preview
                    for (let i = 0; i < plugin.settings.preloaded.length; i++) {
                        $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(plugin.settings.preloaded[i].src, plugin.settings.preloaded[i].id, true));
                    }

            });

        };

        let createContainer = function () {

            // Create the image uploader container
            let $container = $('<div>', {class: 'image-uploader'});

            
            // Create the input type file and append it to the container
            $input = $('<input>', {
                type: 'file',
                id: plugin.settings.imagesInputName,
                name: plugin.settings.imagesInputName + '[]',
                accept: plugin.settings.extensions.join(','),
                multiple: ''
            }).appendTo($container);
            

            // Create the uploaded images container and append it to the container #divInputFile
            let $uploadedContainer = $('<div>', {class: 'uploaded'}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the text container and append it to the container
                $textContainer = $('<div>', {class: 'upload-text'}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the icon and append it to the text container
                $i = $('<i>', {class: 'iui-cloud-upload'}).appendTo($textContainer),

                // Create the text and append it to the text container
                $span = $('<span>', {text: plugin.settings.label}).appendTo($textContainer);


            // Listen to container click and trigger input file click
            $container.on('click', function (e) {
                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);
                // Trigger input click
                $input.trigger('click');
            });

            // Stop propagation on input click
            $input.on("click", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            // Listen to input files changed
            $input.on('change', fileSelectHandler.bind($container));

            return $container;
        };


        let prevent = function (e) {
            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };

        let createImg = function (src, id, preloaded) {

            // Create the upladed image container
            let $container = $('<div>', {class: 'uploaded-image'}),

                // Create the img tag
                $img = $('<img>', {src: src}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the delete button
                $button = $('<button>', {class: 'delete-image'}).appendTo($container),

                // Create the delete icon
                $i = $('<i>', {class: 'iui-close'}).appendTo($button);

            // If the image is preloaded
            if (preloaded) {

                // Set a identifier
                $container.attr('data-preloaded', true);

                // Create the preloaded input and append it to the container
                let $preloaded = $('<input>', {
                    type: 'hidden',
                    name: plugin.settings.preloadedInputName + '[]',
                    value: id
                }).appendTo($container)

            } else {

                // Set the index
                $container.attr('data-index', id);

            }

            // Stop propagation on click
            $container.on("click", function (e) {
                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);
            });

            // Set delete action
            $button.on("click", function (e) {

                // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
                prevent(e);

                // Get the parent element
                let $parent = $container.parent();

                // If is not a preloaded image
                if ($container.data('preloaded') === true) {

                    // Remove from preloaded array
                    plugin.settings.preloaded = plugin.settings.preloaded.filter(function (p) {
                        return p.id !== id;
                    });

                } else {

                    // Get the image index
                    let index = parseInt($container.data('index'));

                    // Update other indexes
                    $parent.find('.uploaded-image[data-index]').each(function (i, cont) {
                        if (i > index) {
                            $(cont).attr('data-index', i - 1);
                        }
                    });

                    // Remove the file from input
                    dataTransfer.items.remove(index);

                    // Update input files
                    $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);
                }

                // Remove this image from the container
                $container.remove();

                // If there is no more uploaded files
                if (!$parent.children().length) {

                    // Remove the 'has-files' class
                    $parent.parent().removeClass('has-files');

                }

            });

            return $container;
        };

        let fileDragHover = function (e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Change the container style
            if (e.type === "dragover") {
                $(this).addClass('drag-over');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('drag-over');
            }
        };

        let fileSelectHandler = function (e) {

            // Prevent browser default event and stop propagation
            prevent(e);

            // Get the jQuery element instance
            let $container = $(this);

            // Get the files as an array of files
            let files = Array.from(e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

            // Will keep only the valid files. La declaro en el fichero de variable globales varGlobales.js
            let validFiles = [];

            // Run through the files
            $(files).each(function (i, file) {
                // Run the validations
                if (plugin.settings.extensions && !validateExtension(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.mimes && !validateMIME(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.maxSize && !validateMaxSize(file)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (plugin.settings.maxFiles && !validateMaxFiles(validFiles.length, file)) {
                    return;
                }
                validFiles.push(file);
            });

            // If there is at least one valid file
            if (validFiles.length) {
                // Change the container style
                $container.removeClass('drag-over');

                // Makes the upload
                setPreview($container, validFiles);

                
            } else {

                // Update input files (it is now empty due to a default browser action)
                $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

            }
            alert("dataTransfer.items.length = " + dataTransfer.items.length.toString())   // visualizo el nº de imagenes capturadas
        };

        let validateExtension = function (file) {

            if (plugin.settings.extensions.indexOf(file.name.replace(new RegExp('^.*\\.'), '.')) < 0) {
                alert('El fichero de imagen "${file.name}" no tiene la extension permitida para ser almacenado: "${plugin.settings.extensions.join(', ')}"');

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        let validateMIME = function (file) {

            if (plugin.settings.mimes.indexOf(file.type) < 0) {
                alert('El fichero de imagen "${file.name}" no tiene la extension permitida para ser almacenado: "${plugin.settings.mimes.join(', ')}"');

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        let validateMaxSize = function (file) {

            if (file.size > plugin.settings.maxSize) {
                alert('La imagen "${file.name}" excede el tamaño maximo de ${plugin.settings.maxSize / 1024 / 1024}Mb');

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        };

        let validateMaxFiles = function (index, file) {

            if ((index + dataTransfer.items.length + plugin.settings.preloaded.length) >= plugin.settings.maxFiles) {
                alert('La imagen "${file.name}" no es posible almacenarla por exceder el limite de imagenes de ${plugin.settings.maxFiles}');

                return false;
            }

            return true;

        };

        let setPreview = function ($container, files) {

            // Add the 'has-files' class
            $container.addClass('has-files');

            // Get the upload images container
            let $uploadedContainer = $container.find('.uploaded'),

                // Get the files input
                $input = $container.find('input[type="file"]');

            // Run through the files
            $(files).each(function (i, file) {

                // Add it to data transfer
                dataTransfer.items.add(file);

                // Set preview
                $uploadedContainer.append(createImg(URL.createObjectURL(file), dataTransfer.items.length - 1), false);

            });

            // Update input files
            $input.prop('files', dataTransfer.files);

        };

        // Generate a random id
        let random = function () {
            return Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        };

        this.init();

        // Return the instance
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Posteriormente en el lado servidor, los datos del formulario capturados en elementos html de tipo

```html
<input name="__NomEquipo" type="text" id="__NomEquipo" class="form-control">
```

los puedo acceder y pasar sus valores cómo parámetros a storeProcedures en el lado servidor del SQL Server del siguiente modo:

```html
' Todo esta Ok. Llamada al Sp para guardado en la bbdd
    Protected Sub GrabacionEquipo()
        Conexiones.AbrirConexion()
        Conexiones.cxInmovilizados.Open() 'Abro la conexión
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("ADOSP_InsertaEquipo", Conexiones.cxInmovilizados) ' Creo un objeto de tipo comando SQL dandole nomnbre al obj e indcando la conexión
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure                                ' Indico que el comando es un StoreProcedure
        ' Creo, asigno y envio los parametros, los cuales deben de llamarse igual que los del SP del Servidor y pasarse con el mismo tipo haciendose el cast si se requiere
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LinCor_Inm", LinkEmailPedido.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LinFul_Inm", LinkFullSteep.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumFac_Inm", NumFac.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumSer_Inm", NumSer.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarMod_Inm", __MarMod.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanRAM_Inm", __CanRam.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModMic_Inm", __ModMic.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CanHD_Inm", __CanRam.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesFin_Inm", DesFin.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomEqu_Inm", __NomEquipo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PetPed_Inm", PetPed.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CtrCar_Inm", __CtrCar.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UbiFis_Inm", __UbiFis.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FecCom_Inm", FecCom.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumInm_Inm", NumInm.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coment_Inm", TxtAreaComentarios.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FecAlt_Inm", FecAlt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FecBaj_Inm", FecBaj.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomDom_Inm", __NomDom.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodBit_Inm", CodBit.Text)
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   ' Ejecuto el SP
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error interno en grabación")
        End Try
        Conexiones.cxInmovilizados.Close() ' Cierro la conexión
    End Sub
```

Mi duda es en **¿cómo puedo pasar el DataTransfer desde el js al lado servidor?**

He leído y visto que lo puedo hacer con **ajax y JSON**, pero desconozco como hacerlo.

También me han aconsejado almacenar las direcciones URL o nombres de las imágenes en lugar de las propias imágenes, pero esto tiene el inconveniente de que las imágenes pueden ser movidas o eliminadas y necesito almacenarlas en la bbdd.

He visto incluso cómo convertir las imágenes en cadenas de bits para ser almacenadas, pero eso es otra duda que deberé solucionar una vez pueda tener el contenido del DataTransfer accesible en el lado servidor y de lo que abriré otro hilo sin o lo consigo solucionar con los hilos ya publicados aquí.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si tomas las imagenes desde un input file deberias convertirlas a base64 y enviarlas al back, ahi pueds convertirlas a jpg, png, etc y guardarlas en una carpeta y luego colocar la ruta a esa imagen en la db. No es buena idea almacenar imagenes. Tal vez esto pueda ayudarte https://youtu.be/zbpYaorDIk8

Comment: Gracias Hernan, lo voy a estudiar en el youtube esta tarde. Me comentas que debo convertirlo a base64 (eso lo puedo ver en otros ejemplos) y me añades que debo enviarlo al back (eso precisamente es la base de mi consulta, que no se como hacerlo con JSON). Espero despejar dudas con el video que me recomiendas.

Comment: sii ya sabes convertirla a base64 aqui te explican como enviarla de 2 maneras distintas con javascript: https://ourcodeworld.co/articulos/leer/76/como-guardar-una-imagen-en-formato-base64-generada-con-javascript-en-el-servidor-con-php.  El video de mas arriba es para convertir base64 a algun formato de imagen y grabarlo a disco con .net c#

Comment: Gracias Hernán, voy a estudiarlo bien, porque todo esto es nuevo para mi. Publicaré el resultado o mis más que seguras futuras dudas, un saludo. ;-)